# Copy QImage to clipboard and survive after app closes?

Tags: linux, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

I am using pyqt5. The following solution does work but the clipboard won't persist after exiting the program as explained in [Copying an image to system clipboard doesn't work on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40950457/3734057).

```
clipboard = QApplication.clipboard()
clipboard.setImage(self.croppedImage)
```

But I need a way to get around this problem. I have seen suggestions of using `xclip`. I tried using it but without success. I am hoping if anyone could give me pointers for this.

Comment: What sort of application are you developing? Why, exactly, do you need the image to persist *on the clipboard* after the user quits the application? There is some suspicion that there may be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) here.

Comment: A screenshot script that copies image into clipboard and exits.

Comment: In that case, the simplest *self-contained* solution would be to run the application as a server and hide/show it instead of restarting it every time. That will then allow you to keep a reference to the image whenever necessary (and also delete it if the clipboard is cleared by other means).

Comment: Yeah, that's the direction I will be heading if nothing works out. :D

Comment: I'm not sure what you are hoping for. Any third-party solution will have to work in exactly the same way. If your application doesn't handle it, your users will have to install a clipboard daemon/manager themselves. That's just the way things are for Qt applications on Linux at the moment.

Comment: yeah, I am aware... sorry if the question was not clear but I was also hoping for someone to give me some pointers on how to use xclip with python to copy qimage in code.